# Effects of Radio-Frequency or Bluetooth Mouses on Laptop Battery Usage

Tags: bluetooth, mice

I'm looking for a new mouse to work with on my laptop. I want it to be wireless, but I'm still deciding between Radio-frequency or Bluetooth. It needs to be precise since I often work with game engines.

While researching, I started questioning the effects each would have on my laptop's battery.

- Does a radio-frequency mouse affect in any way the battery life (at least more than a wired mouse)?
- Would a bluetooth mouse drain it faster than a radio-frequency mouse?
- Does bluetooth version (2.1, 3.0, 4.0) make a difference on laptop battery usage?

Regarding precision and response time, is there a difference between the two?

Finally, any recommendations are also welcome. I prefer bluetooth just because there's no need for an USB port. Also, it needs to be very cheap, around a maximum of 25€.

Comment: What is the difference between "radio-frequency" and Bluetooth? Do you think Bluetooth uses some other means of communication than RF? In any case, the current draw for communications across the meter or so betwixt PC and mouse is negligible compared to CPU, backlight and other drains. WiFi over a *long* distance does matter a bit, since power on transmit must be increased. Consider that the mouse battery lasts for months!

Comment: Discussion of your bullet points is off-topic. And your request for product recommendation is a bit broad.